# How can I get values of cell in dynamique table using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

This is my table, I get data from my database:

```
<c:forEach items="${students }" var="student">
    <tr>
        <td>${student.getName() }</td>
        <td>${student.getAge() }</td>
        <td>${student.getDateNaissance()}</td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to get all the Ages of the students using javascript.

I used this function but it returns just the last age that I insert.

```
function getCurrentDateTime() {
     var table = document.getElementById("datatable");
     for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
             var a = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add your data into an array:

```js
 function getAges() {
    var allAges = [];
    var table = document.getElementById("datatable");
    if(table) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            if(table.rows[i].cells[1])
                allAges.push(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    return allAges;
 }

 console.log(getAges());
```

```html
<table id="datatable">                        
    <tr>
        <td>Toto</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>10/10/10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tata</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>10/10/10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem

```
var a = table.rows[i].cells[1]
```

It should be

```
var a = table.rows[i].cells[j]
```